# Jquery sliders getting the values in between

Tags: jquery, slider, selector

How can I get the value inbetween the two nodes on a jquery slider. I know that you can collect the value of the nodes but how can you collect the values of the space before and between and after the nodes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the minimum and the maximum values selected in the sliders. Then since you know the maximum and minimum values that can sliders can be adjusted to, you can take away the differences to get the values.

lets say sliders can be from 0 to 200 in the slider.

Then lets say 1 slider at 50 means that there is 50 before it. 
then the upper slider minus lower slider  =  middle difference
then max value - upper slider = upper difference.